# Recommended communication pattern for web frontend of command line app

Tags: perl, web-applications, web-frontend, inter-process-communicat

I have a perl app which processes text files from the local filesystem (think about it as an overly-complicated grep).
I want to design a webapp which allows remote users to invoke the perl app by setting the required parameters. 
Once it's running it would be desirable some sort of communication between the perl app and the webapp about the status of the process (running, % done, finished).
Which would be a recommended way of communication between the two processes? I was thinking in a database table, but I'm not really sure it's a good idea.

any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How long does it take to complete the process? Will you allow more than one web user simultaneously?

Comment: It depends on the parameters but between minutes and several hours. The web app should take care of job queuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackers, go ahead and edit this answer to add code examples or links to them.

DrNoone, two approaches come to mind.

1. callback

   Your greppy app needs to offer a callback function that returns the status and which is periodically called by the Web app.
2. event

   This makes sense if you are already using a Web server/app framework which exposes an event loop usable from external applications (rather unlikely in Perl land). The greppy app fires events on status changes and the Web app attaches/listens to them and acts accordingly.

---

For IPC as you envision it, a plain database is not so suitable. Look into message queues instead. For great interop, pick AMPQ compliant implementation.

Comment: Should I wrap the perl app on a Webservice and make the webapp call the webservice or it's an unnecessary layer?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the process using `open($handle, "cmd |")` you can read the results in real time and print them straight to STDOUT while your response is open. That's probably the simplest approach.

Comment: the process output is huge and should be formatted before printing